# Return SQL Agent Job status in SSRS when executing job from SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs

I'm calling a SQL Agent job from SSRS and using a parameter to determine which job to run.

I can run the job(s) just fine. What I'm looking to do is return a message back to the user based on the job status.

Here is how it's executed:

```
IF @Job = 'Run'

BEGIN

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Run selected job'
 
END

IF @Job = 'Delete Previous Run' AND @Confirm = 'DELETE'

BEGIN 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Delete Previous Run'

END
```

When I put `PRINT` into the code after the `EXEC` statement, the only thing that is returned is `Job '<job name>' completed successfully`

I'm hoping to return the SQL Agent status as soon as the job completes. How can I do that?

Comment: You can query job's history. Have a look at `mdsb.dbo.sysjobhistory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sp_start_job` procedure starts the job, then returns to you while the job runs asynchronously. It does not wait for the job to run--just starts it & leaves.

If you want to have your SQL sit & wait for the job to run, you would need to introduce a loop in your T-SQL where you `WAITFOR DELAY 'HH:MI:SS'`, then check the job status, and repeat until the job reaches a terminal status that you can return to the user.

`sp_help_job` will give you the job status, but it uses `#temp` tables, which can cause problems in your code if you try to insert the results of `sp_help_job` into a temp table yourself, you'll hit error 8164, "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."  Some people will use `xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs`, an undocumented, internal procedure that will return similar results. However, because it is undocumented, I prefer not to use it in production code, since the behavior could change in a future version or CU of SQL Server.

Instead, [I prefer to query the tables directly in msdb to determine the job status](https://am2.co/2016/02/xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs_alt/).

Each time around that loop, you would do something like this to get the job status (or grab [the function](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database/blob/production/functions-tvfs/dbo.AgentJob_Status.sql) from [my open-source DBA Database](https://am2.co/dbadb), which I describe further in [my blog post](https://am2.co/2016/02/xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs_alt/) ):

```sql
DECLARE @JobName nvarchar(200) = N'';

SELECT TOP 1
    JobName        = j.name,
    IsRunning      = CASE
                       WHEN ja.job_id IS NOT NULL
                           AND ja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                       END,
    JobLastOutcome = CASE
                       WHEN ja.job_id IS NOT NULL
                           AND ja.stop_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Running'
                       WHEN jh.run_status = 0 THEN 'Failed'
                       WHEN jh.run_status = 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
                       WHEN jh.run_status = 2 THEN 'Retry'
                       WHEN jh.run_status = 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
                     END
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
    ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
       AND ja.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL
       AND ja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON js.job_id = ja.job_id
       AND js.step_id = ja.last_executed_step_id
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh
    ON jh.job_id = j.job_id
       AND jh.instance_id = ja.job_history_id
WHERE j.name = @JobName
ORDER BY ja.start_execution_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Was hoping I could do something without putting a delay into my code